# RequireJS with kendo fails

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, requirejs

I use kendo (2017) and requireJS for my project. When I try to load the following example it gives an error following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoDropDownList is not a function
```

The code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/styles/kendo.common.core.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <!-- Include RequireJS -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.1/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="dropdownlist"></select>
    <script>
    require.config({

      paths: {
        "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min"
      }
    });
console.log(require.config);
    require([ "jquery", "js/kendo.all.min" ], function($, kendo) {
      console.log(kendo)

      $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: {
          data: [{name:"Jane Doe", value: 1}, {name:"John Doe", value: 2}]
        },
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "value"
      });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

But when I add the baseURL and change the config as follows it works.

```
 require.config({
baseUrl: "js", // the path where the kendo scripts are present
      paths: {
        "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min",
      }
    });

    require([ "jquery", "kendo.dropdownlist.min" ], function($, kendo) {
      console.log(kendo)

      $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: {
          data: [{name:"Jane Doe", value: 1}, {name:"John Doe", value: 2}]
        },
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "value"
      });
    });
```

I try to figure It out. But couldn't find any solutions.